# iswritable method in blob in appengine using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob

The blob is checked with a is writable method.

The code used is :

```
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(str);
Boolean writea=file.isWritable();
```

The value of writea displays true. So it refers that the blob is not finalized and can be used again (if I'm right).

Now my question is how to retrieve the blob and use it?

Answer (score 0):

Blobs can not be read while they are writeable. Before you finalize them they are write-only, after that they are read-only.